# how to trigger gpg agent refresh password?

Tags: mac-osx, gpg

We use [StackExchange blackbox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox) as well as [Hiera-eyaml-gpg](https://github.com/sihil/hiera-eyaml-gpg) to encrypt files in our Git repo using GPG keys.

I configured Git to decrypt files using [Textconv](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv) configuration, so it automatically decrypts and compares both blackbox and .eyaml files when I execute commands like `git show ...`, `git diff ...` or `git log -p ...`.

I also use [GPG agent](https://blog.chendry.org/2015/03/13/starting-gpg-agent-in-osx.html) on my OSX, so it remembers the passphrase for a while.

The problem I hit is specifically with eyaml - if I execute `git show HEAD..FETCH_HEAD` and the agent needs to refresh the passphrase then it will automatically pop-up a nice TUI asking to re-type it. This works great if it was triggered via Blackbox but not by `gpg-hiera-eyaml`.

I'd like to find a way to tell gpg "now please ask for the passphrase if needed" directly from the command line, without having to trigger some blackbox command.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is with GPG 1.4.20 on OSX.

EDIT: I tried preset'ing the passphrase with `gpg-preset-passphrase -v -c $(gpg --list-secret-keys --with-fingerprint --with-colons | awk -F: '$1 == "fpr" { print $10 }')` but it doesn't make a difference - `git diff` with eyaml files still tries to read the passphrase and fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gpg-connect-agent RELOADAGENT /bye
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't find this command. I edited the question to specify that this is with GPG 1.4.20 on OS X, in case your answer is relevant to GPG 2.

Comment: @AmosShapira `gpg-connect-agent` is often part of gnupg-agent packages, not gpg/gnupg itself. Also, Matei David did not mention that after the reload you need re-enter the password. Then it is "refreshed".

Comment: Thanks. I got that command on my Mac now that I have GPG 2.0.30 on it too (Homebrew formula `gpg2`) and after running this command and entering my passphrase once, it seems to have stuck and I'm not asked for the passphrase any more after waiting for over an hour.

I have to say that this feels like Voodoo to me since I don't understand what this has to do with solving the problem.

Comment: About the "Voodoo" question - does this `RELOADAGENT` work because it tells the agent to pay attention to the `gpg-preset-passphrase` I mention in my question? Would I still have to keep running the preset passphrase every time I logout and login? (I usually let it sleep).

Comment: It didn't work - I still get asked for the passphrase without being able to enter it correctly.